# Solving solution to Schrodinger Equation by graphing roots on Python

Tags: python, graph, equation

I'm trying to graph the solution to the Schrodinger Equation for a finite potential well. Its a transcendental equation 
f(E) = 2 cot((2mE)<sup>1/2</sup>L/h) + ((U-E)/E)<sup>1/2</sup> - (E/(U-E))<sup>1/2</sup>.

Where E is the variable

My code is giving me a jagged graph.

```
import pylab as pi
import pylab as p
import numpy as np


L = 10e-9 # meters
U = 1.602e-20 # joules
m = 10e-9 # kilograms
h = 1.055e-34 # meters squared * kilograms / seconds


x = p.linspace(0, 1.601999e-20, 1000) # before negative in square root
y = 2/p.tan(2*p.pi*((2*m*x)**(1/2))*(L/h)) + ((U-x)/x)**1/2 - (x/(U-x))**1/2


tol = 100
y[y > tol] = np.nan
y[y < -tol] = np.nan


p.plot(x, y, 'g-', lw=1)
p.show()
```

Can someone help identify the problem?

Comment: Do you use `Python` language? You should label it with `Python` to get more attention

Comment: Sorry about that. Yeah, I do

Comment: There you go, I put `python` tag for you. I could probably see that you sometimes have `1/2` without brackets and sometimes with brackets. You should be careful about that...

Comment: Why do you import `pylab` twice?

Comment: I originally was using matplotlib and was just using pylab for pi. Didn't delete it though.

Comment: What sort of graph do you expect?

Comment: Its supposed to look like a cotangent graph. Even with the square roots.

Comment: The parentheses are not balanced in the original expression. It is not clear whether the Python expression matches it. Also, why did you put 2*pi in the Python expression? You do not have it in the math formula.

Comment: Don't see where I missed parenthesis in either expression. Python isn't giving me any errors.

Comment: I said _in the original expression_, not in Python. Anyway, I fixed that parenthesis. How about the 2*pi thing?

Comment: Well, I had problems graphing tangent and cotangent on matplotlib so I found help graphing them using this code. I'm unfamiliar why the author used 2pi in the function as well. Although when I go to remove it. Python gives me an error.

Comment: If your math formula does not have a 2pi, there is no reason why your Python expression should: `y = 2/p.tan(((2*m*x)**(1/2))*(L/h))...`

Comment: It didn't give me an error, but my problem still persists.

Comment: Looks like you are experiencing the loss of numeric precision. Your variables are very small, but the function has reasonably finite values. I suggest that you renormalize your problem. For example, both `x` and `U` can be multiplied by 1e20. (The other variables have to be scaled accordingly, too.)

Comment: Ok, thanks. That makes sense. I'm sure that's it. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Yup, it definitely fixed the jaggedness.

Comment: Actually, the worst offender is `((2*m*x)**(1/2))*(L/h)`. This value ranges from 0 to 1.7e12 _and_ it is the argument of the (co)tangent! Since (co)tangent is a 2*pi periodic function, the value of (co)tangent at 1000 points between 0 and 1.7e12 is essentially random (including arbitrary large, positively and negatively). There is probably something wrong either with your formula or with the value of your variables.

Comment: The values were determined by my professor.

Comment: and the formula was given

Comment: Actually you are absolutely right. My value for mass is an electron which is 9.11e-34. Big mistake by my part, sorry. Thank you. That helped tremendously.